# Get URI of 3 mp3 files stored in res/raw folder

Tags: android

how can i Get URI of 3 mp3 files stored in res/raw folder, I used : Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.splash) but not work, Do you have suggestions ?

```
public void getSongList(){
    //query external audio
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();

    //Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Uri musicUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.musicplayer/raw/"+R.raw.collide);

    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    //iterate over results if valid
    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        } 
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how to get a `Uri` for those resources. However, there is no `ContentProvider` for those, and so your `query()` will never work. You would need to find some MP3 metadata library that can take an `InputStream` as input and give you back the metadata that you seek.

Also note that many parts of the system do not honor `android.resource` `Uri` schemes, as they are not especially popular.

Comment: OK. I am a beginner in Adroid, and I want to develop an mp3 player

Comment: @Rayan: Most MP3 players work with existing audio files on the device, not on raw resources. A search on `android tutorial "music player"` on a popular search engine turns up many links.

Comment: This project works perfect (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787) for audio files on the device. it is impossible to work with existing audio on raw resources ?

Comment: @Rayan: It is not impossible. You do not need an `android.resource` `Uri` for it. `MediaPlayer` can work with raw resources without a `Uri`. And you can put the title and artist as string resources, as opposed to trying to look them up on the fly.